# Yii framework: get sum by scope

Tags: php, yii, frameworks, get, sum

I have scopes in my User model:

```
public function scopes()
{
    return array(
        'sumPrice'=>array(
             'select'=>'SUM(`price`)',
         ),
    );
}
```

And I want get sumPrice in controller, but I dont know what is a way to do this. I tried:

> $sumPrice=User::model()->sumPrice(); //it returns empty record (user model filled by NULLs)
>
> $sumPrice=User::model()->sumPrice()->count(); //it returns count records in user
>
> $sumPrice=User::model()->sumPrice()->findAll(); //it returns all records in user

But there isn't function which return sum, so how to get it?

**Solved:**

```
$sumPrice = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT SUM(`price`) AS `sum` FROM `user`')->queryAll();
var_dump($sumPrice[0]['sum']);
```

Comment: did you find what you were looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a Statistical query on your active record, define a relation on your model

```
 class Post extends CActiveRecord
 {
     public function relations()
     {
         return array(
             'commentCount'=>array(self::STAT, 'Comment', 'post_id'),
             'categoryCount'=>array(
                 self::STAT, 'Category', 'post_category(post_id, category_id)'
             ),
         );
     }
 }
```

[Yiiframework](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query)

Answer (score 0):

you can use ActiveRecord :

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select='SUM(your_column) as sum';
$criteria->condition='your_condition';
$user = User::model()->find($criteria);
```

and you need to declare: `public $sum;` in your model class. (Using the above example.)

Comment: I tried first example, but there isn't returning sum. I'm getting error: Property "User.sum" is not defined.

Comment: can you var_dump from $sumPrice?

Comment: excuse me, I have edited my answer. try again with $sumPrice->sum